# How to configure NatTable FilterComboBox to have a different DataProvider for each column

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, nattable

In my NatTable I am using a ComboBoxFilterRowHeaderComposite similar to [ExcelLikeFilterRowCustomTypesExample](https://github.com/eclipse/nebula.widgets.nattable/blob/master/org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.examples/src/org/eclipse/nebula/widgets/nattable/examples/_600_GlazedLists/_603_Filter/_6035_ExcelLikeFilterRowCustomTypesExample.java). It works fairly well however the combo box filtering adds too many items in large tables to allow for easy filtering. I am trying to fix this by only filling the combo with certain items, however; in my table some columns are just for types or operations which have a limited amount of different values and I would like to add all options for those. While for other columns I'd like to only add root items.

To achieve this I think I need to modify the comboBoxDataProvider, however; for the full effect that I want it would require a different dataprovider for some columns.

Is this the correct approach? And if so how would I go about doing this?

This is how I am currently configuring my combo box composite:

```
    ComboBoxFilterRowHeaderComposite<GroupedPerfRecord> filterRowHeaderLayer =
            new ComboBoxFilterRowHeaderComposite<GroupedPerfRecord>(
                    bodyLayerStack.getFilterList(),
                    bodyLayerStack.getBodyDataLayer(),
                    bodyLayerStack.getSortedList(),                     
                    columnPropertyAccessor, columnHeaderLayer,
                    columnHeaderDataProvider, configRegistry, false);

    final IComboBoxDataProvider comboBoxDataProvider = filterRowHeaderLayer.getComboBoxDataProvider();
    filterRowHeaderLayer.addConfiguration(new ComboBoxFilterRowConfiguration() {
        {
            this.cellEditor = new FilterRowComboBoxCellEditor(comboBoxDataProvider, 5);
            this.filterIconPainter = new ComboBoxFilterIconPainter(comboBoxDataProvider, GUIHelper.getImage("filter"), null);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a default filter row that has combo boxes for single selection you would use different `IComboBoxDataProvider` for each column. But you have chosen the `ComboBoxFilterRowHeaderComposite` that has a different filtering mechanism in the back to support multi selection and handling of *Select All* similar to well-known spreadsheet applications. So there is no build-in mechanism that would allow to simply configure the desired behavior.

But there is a constructor in the `ComboBoxFilterRowHeaderComposite` that takes a `FilterRowComboBoxDataProvider` as parameter. So you could provide your own implementation of a `FilterRowComboBoxDataProvider` (maybe subclass the `GlazedListsFilterRowComboBoxDataProvider`) and implement the desired behavior in `getValue()` based on the column index.